# How to invoke first thread group if another thread group failed

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, jmx

[image]I am new to Jmeter, and I am trying to achieve the following test plan in Jmeter 4.0.

I have 2 thread group.

- First thread group will generate access token using Oauth 2.0 and the
  value of access token is set to a variable.
- Second Thread group will use the access token generated from first thread group and process the HTTP request.

Token expiration time is 2 hours.

I want to schedule a 8 hours test in Jmeter. How to invoke first thread group to generate token for every 2 hours and to continue thread group 2.

Any help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) after a sampler which could fail
2. Use the following expression as the condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.get('JMeterThread.last_sample_ok').equals('false'),)}
   ```

   where:

   - `JMeterThread.last_sample_ok` is a [pre-defined variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) indicating whether previous sampler was successful or not
   - [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) allows execution of arbitrary [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) code, in above example it checks if the previous sampler is not successful.
3. Put [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) as a child of the If Controller and point it to the 1st Thread Group

More information: [Easily Write a GOTO Statement in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/easily-write-a-goto-statement-in-jmeter)

---

Update: use [Test Fragments](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment)  like:

1. Add Test Fragment to your Test Plan and move the logic from Thread Group 1 there
2. Add Module Controller to Thread Group 1 and reference the Test Fragment
3. In the Module Controller from Thread Group 2 reference the same Test Fragment

   [image: JMeter Test Fragmemts]

Comment: I am not able to select Thread group 1 HTTP request Sampler in my Module controller. Attaching my screenshot for your reference.

Comment: See the update under the horizontal line, it appears you need to use [Test Fragments](https://www.blazemeter.com/ja/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments) instead of referencing the Thread Group 1 in the Module Controller

Comment: Instead of checking previous response status is it possible to execute after certain time interval in if controller ?